# Rebind dymanically created forms after jQuery ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm kinda new to jQuery but understand it for the most part. My problem is that when my ajax call which refreshes the entire div is done, all my dynamically created forms don't work. If you try and submit them, the event doens't work properly and just tries to do a normal form submit. I have all the other items such as links bound using the .live() which seem to work great. Just the form dies.
How do I rebind the dynamically created forms after the ajax call? They all have id of formname_id. I tried to use bind but it doesn't work as below. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
jQuery("form[id^='commentform_']").each(function(){

    var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("commentform_", ""));         

    jQuery(this).bind('submit', function(e) {

        var action     = jQuery('#action_' + id).attr('value');
        var act_id    = ('1');  
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/modify.php",
            data: "action="+ action +"& act_id="+ act_id,
            success: function(response){                
             jQuery('#CommentsContainer_' + id).html(response);
             jQuery('#commentform_' + id)[0].reset();
            }           
        });      
    return false;
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 4):

Try doing something like this:

```
jQuery("form[id^='commentform_']").live('submit',function(){
    var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("commentform_", ""));
    var action = jQuery('#action_' + id).attr('value');
    var act_id = ('1');  
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/modify.php",
        data: {"action": action, "act_id": act_id},
        success: function(response){                
            jQuery('#CommentsContainer_' + id).html(response);
            jQuery('#commentform_' + id)[0].reset();
        }           
    });      
    return false;
});
```

No need to loop over the forms to bind to them.  If you can use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of live do so.

Comment: Good answer. `live()` works as a way to attach an event in such a way that it will work for code that is injected into the DOM after page load. See: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `delegate()` is the new better faster version of `live()` if your lookin' for performance.

Comment: @perter Thanks but that did not work. It still tries to submit the form.

Comment: Accoding to the link about live you can't use it for submits. "In jQuery 1.3.x only the following JavaScript events (in addition to custom events) could be bound with .live(): click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup. " Any other suggestions??

Comment: You can upgrade to 1.4 (recommended) or re-bind the submit event every  time you reload the forms

Comment: @perter I'm already using 1.4.2. and it still doesn't work for me. Any ideas? It will not work with .live there for me. :/
How do I re-bind every time I reload the forms then?

Comment: Ahh.. I've been pulling out my hair to find out it's a bug in jQuery 1.4.2
http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6359

When I revert back to 1.4.1 it works perfectly.
@peter thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you over-ride the normal form submit:

```
    function addNewitem() {
        $('#new_item_form').submit(function() {
            $.get("includes/ItemEdit.php", {
                newItem: true
            },
            function(msg) {
                isNewItem = true;
                $("#new_item").hide();
                $('#item_list').hide();
                $("#item_edit").html( msg );
                $("#item_edit").show();
                editActiveEvent();
            });
            return false;
        });

    }
```

Don't forget to return false. or do a `.preventDefault`

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this to work adding the event in the function call and using event.preventDefault();  BUT of course only in FF. Doesn't work in IE7..

```
jQuery("form[id^='commentform_']").live('submit',function(event){ 
var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("commentform_", "")); 
var action = jQuery('#action_' + id).attr('value'); 
var act_id = ('1');   
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ajax/modify.php", 
    data: {"action": action, "act_id": act_id}, 
    success: function(response){                 
        jQuery('#CommentsContainer_' + id).html(response); 
        jQuery('#commentform_' + id)[0].reset(); 
    }            
});       
event.preventDefault();});
```

But IE7 still tries to sumbit the action. arrgggh.. Anything I'm doing wrong??

Comment: This works fine using the event.preventDefault();
But doenst work in IE with 1.4.2. Use 1.4.1 until its fixed in the next version.
http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6359